# How to map the space/insert whitespace key to a some key for the evil mode?

Tags: key-bindings, evil

Good day,

I am struggling with remapping the space key functionality. In particular, when I am using emacs with the evil mode I want to be able to use space when moving around in normal mode.
I would like to map insert whitespace to `M-SPC`. However, since there seems to be no function for inserting space I don't know how to make it work. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [kbd](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Sequences.html) for defining the keybinding. You can look up the string that `kbd` expects by using `C-h k` `M-SPC`. Subsequently, you can just use the `insert` function inside a command to insert some string. A command is just a function starting with an [interactive special form](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html).

Finally, you can either define your custom named command and bind that, or use an anonymous command directly as follows:

```lisp
(evil-global-set-key 'normal (kbd "M-SPC") (lambda () (interactive) (insert " ")))
```

Comment: Wow, this is genius, this works right of the scratch.